# Symfony app on Google app Engine, invalid bucket name

Tags: php, symfony, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I want to use Symfony app on google app engine to create an API, so far I installed the app but when I hit Run and later on Browse on the local GAE is showing me the following error

[image]

This is my app.yml file with the bucket name set

```
# Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
application: rtw-api
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
# tell appengine where our static assets live
- url: /bundles
  static_dir: web/bundles

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: web/robots.txt
  upload: web/robots.txt

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: web/favicon.ico
  upload: web/favicon.ico

# a script to clear our cache
- url: /clear_cache
  script: web/clear_cache.php
  login: admin

# the symfony front controller
- url: /.*
  script: web/app.php

env_variables:
  GCS_BUCKET_NAME: "rtw_api"

skip_files:
  - (.*/)?Tests\/Fixtures\/(.*)
  - ^app\/cache\/(.*)
```

this is my php.ini file

```
; Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
display_errors=0
google_app_engine.enable_functions="php_sapi_name, libxml_disable_entity_loader"
google_app_engine.allow_include_gs_buckets=rtw_api
```

I already created the bucket for my project as you can see here

[image]

For some reason symfony is appending the None string to the bucket name.

All the above only shows when I have the enviroment in development and debugging set to true

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev',true);
```

If I change it for

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod',false);
```

I get a nice Homepage text as if everything was working on.

Any ideas how to solve the issue with the bucket ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you use this as a starting point for your project? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-symfony-starter-project

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but using an underscore, `_`, in a bucket name is counter-indicated in the GCS docs: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming

Comment: @JG Estevez I would suggest to try using the full notation of bucket names, i.s. gs://rtw-api (instead of just rtw-api)